# Didnt receive any value in RecycleView in my fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, fragment

Previously I have success list out my data from cloud firestore in my app. But right now I'm trying to implement RecyclerView that list out the data in my fragment but I didn't get results. The fragment shows empty result. Here is my code

**ReviewFragment.java**

```
public class ReviewFragment extends Fragment {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference userRef = db.collection("Users");
    private UserAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_review,container,false);
        Query query = userRef.orderBy("name",Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Userz> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Userz>()
                .setQuery(query,Userz.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new UserAdapter(options);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.rvReview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**UserAdapter.java**

```
public class UserAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter <Userz,UserAdapter.UserHolder>{


    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See
     * {@link FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public UserAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Userz> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(UserHolder userHolder, int i, Userz userz) {
        userHolder.textViewName.setText(userz.getName());
        userHolder.textViewStatus.setText(userz.getStatus());
        userHolder.textViewMessage.setText(userz.getMessages());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);
        return new UserHolder(v);
    }

    class UserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewMessage;
        TextView textViewStatus;
        public UserHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            textViewMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messages);
            textViewStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirestorePagingAdapter lifecycle
Start/stop listening
The FirestorePagingAdapter listens for scrolling events and loads additional pages from the database only when needed.

To begin populating data, call the startListening() method. You may want to call this in your onStart() method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling startListening() or your query will fail.

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
Similarly, the stopListening() call freezes the data in the RecyclerView and prevents any future loading of data pages.

Call this method when the containing Activity or Fragment stops:

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.stopListening();
}
```

Automatic listening
If you don't want to manually start/stop listening you can use Android Architecture Components to automatically manage the lifecycle of the FirestorePagingAdapter.
Pass a LifecycleOwner to FirestorePagingOptions.Builder#setLifecycleOwner(...) and FirebaseUI will automatically start and stop listening in onStart() and onStop().

Github https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore

Answer (score 0):

You don't have getCount() method in you adapter class. implement the method and return size of list.